# netsystemsresearch.com on my internal network

Tags: network-security

It first started happening with the local network enabled printer. It printed out that netsystemsresearch.com was doing a search of all public networks. I stopped that by disabling outside connections from the printer.

Yesterday I had an expressjs server running locally on my machine (on port 3000), and I got a ping from netsystemsresearch.com again with the same  message.

Anybody has experienced something like that? I tried looking up netsystemsresearch.com but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

I made the same observation as you did on my local network.

With this scan: https://urlscan.io/domain/netsystemsresearch.com
I found the following entry in their DNS Records:

Net Systems Research conducts periodic scans of the Internet to identify fraudulent activity for our customers. Our scans are CFAA compliant; however if you wish to be excluded from our scans please contact us at abuse@netsystemsresearch.com.

Answer (score 0):

It appeared in my reports from the address: 92.118.161.21.
And an examination I did on [abuseipdb](https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/92.118.161.21), shows that this is allegedly a malicious address.